# How do I get UWP Uninstall to remove database completely?

Tags: entity-framework-6, windows-store, xaf, desktop-bridge

I have managed to get an XAF application into the Windows Store via the Desktop Bridge.

When a user installs my software from the Windows Store and then chooses to uninstall, 
I want them to have the option to completely uninstall the software including the database. 
So that they won't have any problem should they later decide to re-install?

Currently, the UWP uninstall does not give an option to delete the database ( or even explain how to delete it ) Thus the user may be tempted to delete the data files via Windows Explorer - which still leaves some instance of LocalDB maintaining an entry in its list of databases.

Thus on a second install after deleting the database files, the UWP program displays the error

```
"Login failed for user"
```

As explained [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53788367/exception-occurred-while-initializing-the-database-login-failed-for-user-on-re/53796927#53796927)

My connection string is using

```
(localdb)\mssqllocaldb
```

How do I automate removing the database and memory of it completely?

i.e What uninstall event can I use, What do I override where?

I can't see any executable code in the Desktop Bridge itself.

At the moment I think I may need to put "Run This Before You Uninstall" option in the actual program.

Or perhaps as a workaround, I should code a Clean Up handler for the "Login failed for user" error.

[This issue is related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53909226/why-cant-i-see-a-database-created-by-a-uwp-desktop-bridge-app-in-the-sql-serve)

I am using Entity Framework 6.2 and .Net Framework 4.7.2

The Bridge Project is using Windows 10, version 1809, Build 17763 ( Min and Target)

Comment: Do you mean that you want to remove database within uwp?

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT Yes I want an option to do that. Note from the other question just deleting the database and log files is not enough.

Comment: There seem to be some hints at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15318843/localdb-how-do-you-delete-it

Comment: The original database will not cause  **Login failed for user**, Have you check another issue about this?

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT  Yes and things are worse now https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53877961/the-underlying-provider-failed-on-open-after-deleting-database-files-and-sqlloca

Comment: Is dropping all of the tables sufficient?

Comment: @tiagoperes that would not remove the database completely which is what I want.  It could be a work around for the reinstall issue though.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.packageuninstallingeventargs

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53909226/what-localdb-instance-does-desktop-bridge-use

Comment: @KirstenGreed probably you don't really need a solution as drastic to get needed results / fix the problem you're going though. Therefore, my suggestion is to adapt the current question and drop the tables. If you still encounter problems later on the path with this solution, then remove the database will be the next step.

Comment: @tiagoperes  On what event would i do that?

Answer (score 0):

See ***[Getting Started with EF Core on Universal Windows Platform (UWP) with a New Database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/uwp/getting-started)***. It introduces use of migrations. Migrations are designed to help you change your database design and implement the changes in production. Migrations can be frustrating though because Microsoft has not documented the feature thoroughly. There is a list somewhere of the migration features not supported for SQLite; it is important to know about that from the beginning.

Comment: Comment on this answer if you need a different answer

Comment: The issue has nothing to do with OneNote

Comment: Oh. Sorry I know how to do it with one note but I thought thats is what is with

Comment: I updated my question to show I am using EF 6.2. I am also using Migrations I don't think that has anything to do with the problem.